# Access to Random Files in Random Directories in C#

Tags: c#, .net, file

For a testsuite to test some Replication scenarios I write a FileAccesser. This should access random files (in random subdirectories) in a given directory and Delete, Create, Rename and change the file or/and content. I am looking for a way to access a random file in a random subdirectory. Any suggestions?

My Solution to get a List of all files in all Subdirectories is:

```
var _Directory = new DirectoryInfo(args[1]);
var _Files = _Directory.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Now i can access to a Random File with

```
Random _Random = new Random();
var _RandomFile = _Files.ElementAt(_Random.Next(_Files.Count()));
```

THX for your help.

Comment: How about just listing all files with `Directory.GetFiles` and then choosing a random one?

Comment: Directory.GetFiles return a list of files in a given directory. I need a recursive GetFiles Function

Comment: Then you can either implement recursion yourself or use `SearchOption.AllDirectories` as third parameter.

Comment: Can you Post your Comment as Answer, i can set my question to solved than.

Answer (score 4):

I think I understand what you want to do but the use of randomness for testing seems like the wrong thing to do here.

I hope I'm not teaching anyone to suck eggs here but tests are supposed to be repeatable and measurable. If any test fails you need to be able to step through and identify what went wrong and correct it.

If you can modify the properties and contents of a file in one directory, then you should be able to do it in any as long as all the parameters of the test are the same. If the parameters of the test change then the scope of the test increases (eg, permissions on a directory or file make it read-only).

Comment: Thx for your answer, you are right. For the replication Test i has Build a scenario with separate Steps. But now i want test the Replicationtimes and in the productive system some users access to random Files and Change the Content or the File himself. What i want to do now is to synchronize both servers (with NTP) and start the randomaccesser on the master (this will log me a CSV: timestamp;servername;file;method;filesize) and the replication monitor is a file watcher who create also a CSV with timestamp;servername;file;method,filesize so than i can check the Timestamps and see what happen

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like :

- Create a List of all directories (as list of string)
- For each directory create a List of files in it.
- Using a Random generator generate a number between 0 and list of dir count.
- Select the dir from the list based on the above generated number as index.
- Apply the last 2 steps for selecting a random file for above selected directory.

Comment: Thx for your answer, the directory is like a tree with a lot of subdirectories and a deep about 10 levels. Can i serialize the Files in all subdirectories?

Comment: Yes you can traverse the whole tree using recursive function.

Comment: if i'd do that, I'd generate a flat list of complete paths

Comment: @Sebastian Edelmeier : Yes, that what needs to be done. List<string> where each element is complete path of a dir

Answer (score 1):

- Create a list of strings, each string represent a file path (Directory\FileName.ext)
- Generate random number 0 - length of the string-1
- Get the index based on the random numnber